# hide curl_easy_perform

Tags: c, libcurl

How can I hide curl_easy_perform output (in a shell)?
This is in regards to a C application.

Comment: Curl_easy_perform prints the page content returned in response to a request (post request in my case). I want "hide" that page content (no view) and print my personal message

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and/or `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` options:

```
FILE *f = fopen("target.txt", "wb");
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, f);
```

By default, libcurl writes output to `stdout`.  When you override this (which is what almost any application will do), it will write to another file or to pass chunks of output to a callback.  See the documentation for [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but I know this. There isn't a way without "deviate" the output (a way to delete it)?

Comment: @stdio - If you just want the input to  go away, open a NULL device and print everything there.

Comment: @Tm Post: do you mean /dev/null? if you mean this, the code would not be multiplatform.

Comment: FILE* devnull = fopen("nul", "w"); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, devnull);

Comment: does `fopen("nul", "w")` works for both linux and windows?

Answer (score 25):

Use CURLOPT_NOBODY in curl_easy_setopt().
Example:

```
 ...

CURL *curl;
CURLcode statusCode;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl){
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/");
    //CURLOPT_NOBODY does the trick
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);

 ...
```

Link to docs: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTNOBODY

Comment: I wanted to log into a page https://user:pass@www.example.com/login/ and then use curl to POST to https://www.example.com/upload/ but with CURLOPT_NOBODY I lose the session-id. I solved this by writing to nul

Comment: Am I right to suppose this is useful for POST requests, but probably not so for GET?

Comment: for POST requests, this simply does not send the body, meaning it's not what you would expect.

Answer (score 7):

As [Joey said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814988/c-hide-curl-easy-perform/2815027#2815027), `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` will allow you to completely disregard all output. Just set up a callback that does absolutely nothing if you want the data to just go away, without being written to any file descriptor.

For instance,

```
/* Never writes anything, just returns the size presented */
size_t my_dummy_write(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
   return size * nmemb;
}
```

Then in your options:

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &my_dummy_write);
```

Or, point the file handle at a NULL device (a lot easier).